# Create a circular indicator using a custom class has width and height too large

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make an circular indicator using `CAShapeLayer`. I am doing this in a custom class so I can reuse it for every `UIView`.

This is what I have for now:

```
class CircularIndicator: UIView {

    var circularIndicator = CAShapeLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        configure()
    }

    func configure() {
        let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width / 2, y: self.bounds.width / 2)
        let circleRadius = self.bounds.size.width / 2
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerPoint, radius: circleRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(-0.5 * M_PI), endAngle: CGFloat(1.5 * M_PI), clockwise: true)

        circularIndicator.path = circlePath.cgPath
        circularIndicator.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        circularIndicator.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        circularIndicator.lineWidth = 6
        circularIndicator.strokeStart = 0
        circularIndicator.strokeEnd = 1

        self.layer.addSublayer(circularIndicator)
    }
}
```

I added an `UIView` in the main view controller with height and width = 150. My issue is that when I run the app, the `circleRadius` value ends up being 500, which makes the circle way bigger.

My understand is that `self.bounds.witdh` or `self.bounds.height` should equal the value of the `UIView` which contains this class. 
Am I wrong on this ? How come I end up with value so large for width and height ?

Comment: Ok, apparently I have to do the radius calculations inside layoutSubViews. Then I will get the correct values.

Comment: Yup. You should either accept Rob's answer or post your own answer and accept that, so the question is marked as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the `frame` may change. So you should set the `path` in `layoutSubviews`:

```
class CircularIndicator: UIView {

    var circularIndicator = CAShapeLayer()
    var lineWidth: CGFloat = 6

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        configure()
    }

    private func configure() {
        circularIndicator.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        circularIndicator.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        circularIndicator.lineWidth = lineWidth
        circularIndicator.strokeStart = 0
        circularIndicator.strokeEnd = 1

        layer.addSublayer(circularIndicator)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: bounds.width / 2, y: bounds.width / 2)
        let circleRadius = (bounds.size.width - lineWidth) / 2

        circularIndicator.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerPoint, radius: circleRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(-0.5 * M_PI), endAngle: CGFloat(1.5 * M_PI), clockwise: true).cgPath
    }
}
```

By the way, you may want to inset the circle by half of the `lineWidth`, as shown above, where I adjust the `circleRadius` accordingly. Otherwise, the edges of the circle will exceed the `frame` of the view.